# Hide empty fields in webform's preview page

Tags: webform-civicrm

Is there a way to hide empty fields or field sets in a webform? The preview page shows everything single field and I have a lot of them!

regards,

Guillaume

Comment: i don't quite follow. When you Preview a webform why should it not show all the fields?

Comment: because some are empty. I offer the possibility to register a lot of contacts for those who need. Some owner need to register 3 sub-organizations and others 15. It goes up to 24 sub-organizations if needed! I used the webform "Add more" module. It works fine but by the preview, it shows all empty fields. You can have a look here: https://cnec.gestad.net/adhesion

Comment: see if the same behaviour happens purely with webform ie without civicrm fields - if so this is a pure webform issue